# How to decide that some object should not be declared static?

Tags: java, android, static

My rule is that in case of primitives, I can declare them `static` any time I want as they will not consume much memory. In practice, I usually use `static` primitives as project constants.

However, I saw many programmers declare objects as `static` as well. Obviously `static` object will increase memory consumption with each new `static` object.

For example, I often see that `sharedpreference` object is declared static so that any class can have updated information from it by calling `apply()` from anywhere in the code. I don't use it, but I create is as instance object instead and handle the login in a different manner.

So, how shall we be sure that we can safely declare some object as `static`? Do we try to predict its memory consumption or there is some other better method?

The reason for the question is the project that occupied 100MB or RAM on the mobile device. Static objects were used unnecessarily so a lot of data was kept in RAM without need. Once I converted static objects to instance objects, memory consumption dropped to 60MB.

PS. I have seen horrible cases of using static objects in the app just because programmers were lazy to properly handle the logic and such apps consumed up to 100% more memory than they should.

Comment: This has nothing to do with how much memory they take, rather with what static implies.

If your primitive should be unique and be able to be different for each instance of the class, don't make it static, much memory or not.

The same goes for an Object

Comment: as a sidenote, an enum is rather a better alternative to the static constants.

Answer (score 5):

This

> Obviously static object will increase memory consumption with each new static object.

is simply wrong: a static reference won't consume more or less memory than a non-static one.

Of course the static referenced object will stay in memory, as long as the class with the reference stays in memory, which might be until the end of the JVM.

On the other hand if every instance that needs `A` creates and holds an instance of `A` that will consume much more memory than a single `A` for everybody.

But memory consumption is really irrelevant in 99% of the cases, so I normally only think about it when I start having problems, or it becomes obvious I will get problems if I don't consider it.

More important are criteria like the following:

1. Will I ever want a different instance, for example for testing.
2. Does really everybody all the time need the same instance?
3. Might I want to use inheritance
4. When in doubt, don't use static

**Regarding the updated question, which clarified that OP is asking about memory constraint devices**

It sounds like someone is using static referenced Objects on a memory constraint device as some kind of cache, i.e. in order to avoid recreation of some object.

Based on that assumption the reasoning is somewhat different the result is more or less the same:

1. Don't cache stuff until you know you need it
2. If you cache something, make sure it helps you achieving your performance goal, by actually measuring
3. Make sure nothing else breaks, in this case especially memory constraints
4. If in doubt: don't cache

Finally: If you need a cache, use a cache, not some hacked solution like an abused static reference.

Comment: Static object will live as long as the app lives, right? So the memory it occupies does not day die until the app's process dies. True? This is important in app that run on mobile devices.

Comment: Tried to address the aspect brought into the game by your comments and the edit to the question.

Answer (score 4):

You have this completely back to front. It is *instance* variables that will use more memory, and it is *static* variables that need a strong motivation for making them static. If you don't already have a good reason for making them static, thy shouldn't be.

> PS. I have seen horrible cases of using static objects in the app just because programmers were lazy to properly handle the logic and such apps consumed up to 100% more memory than they should.

Complete and utter nonsense. You have never seen any such thing. Using static variables doesn't double the memory, unless the class is never instantiated at all.

Comment: I have done memory profiling in those project so I am sure. The static objects unnecessarily held data and occupied memory in a way that memory consumption increased from 50-60MB to close to 100MB or over. Once those object were converted to instance object that die with each screen, memory dropped to 60MB. Still nonsense?

Comment: Not once you've explained it properly. The way it was stated in the question, definitely.

Comment: Edited! So in your opinion, how to know if static object will consume too much memory?